# Can't select other languages from google input tools

Tags: html, google-translate

I am using google input tools to make create different languages such as Spanis,Greek,Turkish etc.. 
My code is given below

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var editorId='';
      // Load the Google Transliterate API
      google.load("elements", "1", {
            packages: "transliteration"
          });

      function onLoad() {
        var options = {
          sourceLanguage: 'en',
          destinationLanguage: ['el','kn','ml','ta','te'],
          shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
          transliterationEnabled: true
        };

        // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
        // options.
        var control =
            new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

        // Enable transliteration in the textfields with the given ids.
        var ids = [ "transl2" ];
        control.makeTransliteratable(ids);

        // Show the transliteration control which can be used to toggle between
        // English and Hindi and also choose other destination language.
        control.showControl('translControl');
      }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
      console.log(google);
    </script>



 <script>
```

**The problem is that :** Translator translating Indian languages only. When I am try to change destination language as  **destination language: as ['es']** Which show error that google language array does not contain **'es'** but google says es is for spanish language. How could I solve it??

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add Spanish as a destination language. Here is a list of languages that you can add as the destination language.

```
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.AMHARIC,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ARABIC,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.BENGALI,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.CHINESE,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.GREEK,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.GUJARATI,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.HINDI,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.KANNADA,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.MALAYALAM,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.MARATHI,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.NEPALI,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ORIYA,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.PERSIAN,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.PUNJABI,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.RUSSIAN,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.SANSKRIT,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.SERBIAN,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.SINHALESE,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.TAMIL,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.TELUGU,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.TIGRINYA,
    google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.URDU
```

More information can be found on [Google Transliterate API Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started#SupportedDestinationLanguages)